# Has the same value when using conditions for subtraction

Tags: java, android, loops

```
    for (int i = 0; i < listAnswers2.size(); i++) {
        View view = listAnswers2.get(i).getView();
        allWidth += (float) view.getWidth() + 20F;

        if(view == listAnswers2.getFirst().getView()) {
            Log.e("allWidth 2", String.valueOf(allWidth));
        } else {
            allWidth -= (float) view.getWidth() + 20F;
            Log.e("allWidth", String.valueOf(allWidth));
        }
    }
```

I have a case where the above code has the same value for its output, like this value generated:

227.0

227.0

227.0

If I do not use conditions like the code below:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < listAnswers2.size(); i++) {
        View view = listAnswers2.get(i).getView();
        allWidth += (float) view.getWidth() + 20F;

        Log.e("allWidth", String.valueOf(allWidth));
    }
```

has an output like this:

227.0

394.0

667.0

But the output was not what I wanted, but the value I wanted was like this:

0.0

227.0

394.0

Can anyone provide a solution for this case? Or is there an alternative to this case without using the condition? Please help me

Comment: It's entirely unclear what you're asking.  What are you trying to achieve, and how does your expected output relate to your input?

Comment: which I want to achieve for the result is as I have explained earlier, if I do not use the condition results like this

227.0

394.0

667.0

but I do not want that, but I want the result of its value like this:

0.0

227.0

394.0

what I'm still not clear asked?

Comment: No.  I have no idea what you mean.  Never mind. Hopefully there's someone smarter than me out there who will come and answer your question for you.

Comment: Thank you @DawoodibnKareem for responding though not giving a solution to my case

Comment: I can see that your loop index, i, must be 0, 1, 2; but what sort of object is a listAnswers2, so we can know what behavior to expect from getFirst()? Also, it would help if you showed the "allWidth 2" or "allWidth" part of your log file so we could know which condition (evaluating view == getView()) is being hit. And, is it reasonable to expect view.getWidth() to return zero for the first item in your list? (I'm assuming allWidth is initialized to zero above in your code. But a zero width for anything seems somewhat anomalous.)

Comment: In general, I expect adding more log/print statements to your code will enlighten you.

Comment: @Tamias I do not think it makes sense, but is there no other way to meet the expectations of the value results than I expected?

Comment: Your code would be much more readable if you used the Enhanced For-Loop. https://blogs.oracle.com/corejavatechtips/using-enhanced-for-loops-with-your-classes

Comment: We don't understand what the program is intended to do. It looks like you are trying to compute the width of a viewport. Why are you adding 20 units and subtracting 20 later? It looks like a poorly designed algorithm.

Comment: @WilliamJohnHolden Actually the purpose to ask like this to shift the deleted object on LinkedList <> bro. So I use this method but the method is not effective because the stack is in value 227.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that **allWidth** is a float that starts with **0.0** your code could be something like this:

```
float allWidth = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < listAnswers2.size(); i++) {
    Log.e("allWidth", String.valueOf(allWidth));
    View view = listAnswers2.get(i).getView();
    allWidth += (float) view.getWidth() + 20F;
}
```

Comment: Yes I understand, the initial variables are so, but for loopingnya results are not as I expected. Actually for this case for animate problem for object deletion.

Comment: Ok. Test the code above first and give me the output.

Comment: thanks bro, the output is in accordance with what I expect it turns out. Sorry sorry I did not check back the code you gave :D

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < listAnswers2.size(); i++) {
    if(view == listAnswers2.getFirst().getView()) {
        Log.e("allWidth 2", String.valueOf(allWidth));
     } else {
           allWidth -= (float) view.getWidth() + 20F;
           Log.e("allWidth", String.valueOf(allWidth));
        }

      View view = listAnswers2.get(i).getView();
      allWidth += (float) view.getWidth() + 20F;

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question, but please answer not to perfunctory.

Comment: What answer you are getting with this logic ?